# AJAX with a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, ajax

I'm new to AJAX and JavaScript, but decided to tackle sending a value based on an HTML "" tag using Ajax to a Python handler. Below is my code, simulated from this [site](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/check-if-check-box-is-checked-using-php-and-ajax). The problem I'm having is understanding when a box is "checked" vs "unchecked", how does the value get passed, when I have "unchecked" in the input tag? I'm not getting the connection as I want to make sure that whatever the user clicks gets passed through AJAX to my Python Handler.

```js
send_data = function(status) {

        $.ajax({
      url: "/subscription",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {'status' : status},
            type: "POST",
            cache: false

    }).done(function(data, status, xml) {

         var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
         alert(obj.success);

        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {


        }).always(function() {


        });

}


$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#subscription").submit(function() {

        var cb = $("input#switch-1");

        if (cb.is("checked")) {
            send_data(cb.val());
        } else {
            send_data(cb.val());
        }
        return false; 
    });

});
```

```html
<form id="subscription" action="">
    <label  class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-1">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch-1" name="status" class="mdl-switch__input" id="status" unchecked />
    <span class="mdl-switch__label">USEREMAIL Subscribed</span>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Comment: I guess `id="status"` should be `name="status"`, since this input already has an id.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the correct selector is [:checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).
Аnd you should pass checkbox value to send_data() function only when it's checked, otherwise your condition is irrelevant - you are doing the same thing for checked and not checked inputs.

So, your code should be something like this:

```
if (cb.is(":checked")) {
    send_data(cb.val());
} else {
    send_data(null);
}
```

But if all you need is pass form values to server, you don't need to handle checkbox manually, you can just do this:

```
var send_data = function(data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/subscription",
        dataType: "json",
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        cache: false
    }).done(function(data, status, xml) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        alert(obj.success);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }).always(function() {

    });
}

$("#subscription").submit(function() {
    send_data($(this).serialize());
});
```

Note, that if checbox is not checked, it's value won't be sent to server (it's a default browser behaviour). So you can just check presense of status field in your backend script.

Comment: Hi Alexey, Thanks for the feedback. I tried to add your code, but got a "405 Method Not Allowed". I first thought it was an issue with my python handler, but its something with the javascript now I believe. I was able to test with my handler using my other code, but I don't get the status value passed. Not sure what I'm missing :-).

Comment: Attached is my handler, but I am still having issues with how status gets passed:                                                                                                                             class Subscription(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):
        subscription_status = self.request.get('status')
        user_name = users.get_current_user()
        logging.info(' I got here: %s!', user_name)
        logging.info('Status is: %s!', subscription_status)

Comment: All I can say is this: 1) I've changed only how post data is sent to server, it should not result in 405 error; 2) as I pointed out in the comments, your input doesn't have a "name" attribute, so it's value won't be sent to server, probably, it's why your code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code can be reduced like this, you are doing the verification in vain, in both cases you are sending the same thing...

```
$("#subscription").submit(function() {
    var cb = $("input#switch-1");
    send_data(cb.val()); //your current code can be reduced like this
    return false; 
});
```

If you want to see what is passed, just print with python what you receive via the checkbox name...

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thank you! Sorry, on the 101 here. I added your code, but I don't see the actual value passed. I enabled the console, what am I missing on why the checked vs unchecked is not passed: http://postimg.org/image/tdhm5k34x/.

Comment: @user2690151, well, the error in the console is pretty self-explanatory - you should run this code on a proper web server via http protocol, not via _file://_